# Best practices to deploy grails app w/wo Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, web-deployment, war

I actually have one server with many tomcats to deploy grails with War files, And, every 3 months we ran a server scan to search for vulnerabilities, we usually find out that the Tomcat version installed needs and upgrade, and this is difficult because not only we need to upgrade Tomcat but also re-configure the whole thing (files, connectors, ssl certificates, etc).

So with that in mind, I wonder if there is another way to make the upgrades easier (i.e by saving the settings) or the deployment of grails app without Tomcat

Comment: "...or the deployment of grails app without Tomcat" - You can deploy your app without tomcat as long as you are using some other supported container, but mostly you are going to have the same types of issues with other containers.

Answer (score 0):

I started to deploy only runnable jars instead of wars that must be deployed in containers ("make jar, not war"). This helps to be flexible and keep the application compact. Although Grails 4+ names their standalone app xyz.war, but it´s runnable.
Check https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html

In terms of ssl or connectors, I tend to use nginx as a proxy that handles the ssl stuff and redirects domains to a certain ports. This perfectly works with multiple applications. You can even use Docker for example.